# share folder via Dropbox Ruby API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropbox

I want to share a dropbox folder via the Ruby API.
Is it possible now or is there anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There is always a way, but in this case it would require you to login programmatically via cURL and pass back and forth the data needed.  I am trying to figure that out now myself.

[Edit]

Since there's still interest in this thread I'll post the basic instructions, it may have changed since I did this, but this is what was working 6 months ago.

1) You need to log in and remember your cookies.

The login URL is (was) `https://www.dropbox.com/login`

The data you need to post to the login page is below represented as a php array since that's what I used.

```
$loginData = array(
    't' => $loginToken,
    'login_email' => $_POST['input_from_email'],
    'login_password' => $_POST['input_from_email_password']
);
```

The login token is part of the login form and is to prevent XSS so you need to read it from there and include it in your form post or else it will fail.

Once you successfully login  you have need to read in the HTML and headers using cURL for the url `https://www.dropbox.com/home` and parse the

```
preg_match("/.*TOKEN:(.*),.*/", $homeResponse, $homeResponseMatches);
```

This pulls the XSS token for the next form which is the form that submits and creates the share.  it is used by posting to the URL `https://www.dropbox.com/share_ajax/new`.  and the data that needs to be posted is.

```
$createShareData = array(
    'emails' => $_POST['input_to_email'],
    'custom_message' => $_POST['input_message'],
    'folder_name' => $_POST['input_folder_name'],
    't' => $loggedInToken
);
```

'$loggedInToken' is the token you scraped from `https://www.dropbox.com/home`.  This will create a new folder and share it with the emails in the 'emails' field which is a comma delimited list of email addresses.

Have fun.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I'm in the middle of trying to do the very same thing right now, and I'm coming up dry.

Comment: Yes I did, it's fairly straight forward, 2 form posts, one to log in, holding the cookies as then another to create the shared folder.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: answer updated. It basically gives you what you need to go through but doesn't give you code, since YOu may not be using php and the code I wrote was for a client.  I can't really just share that, but the method I can share.

Comment: When sharing a folder, The data you send in POST now has the additional option `allow_other_members_to_share: on`. It's also work noting that to invite multiple emails at once, just add an additional "emails" parameter to the POST query, like `emails=email1@domain.com&emails=email2@domain.com`.

Comment: Also, I'm currently getting away just fine without sending `t` with my login data, so they must have removed that.

Comment: @Dan did you complete this? If so could you share the full code?

Comment: I needed a solution in Node.JS, so that's what my code is written in. I haven't used it recently, so it may or may not still work. Either way, you should at least be able to get an idea by looking at what I came up with: http://pastebin.com/fy04JD8D . Ultimately, dealing with Dropbox was too much of a hassle and I rewrote my entire application to use a self-hosted cloud storage service that I had more control over.

Answer (score 1):

I've been scouring the API and the dev forum, and unforuntately I do not think it's possible (at least not in any straight forward manner).

http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=25478&replies=10

http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=22779