# Sharing File or Folder link to list of Email ids

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, dropbox, add-in, dropbox-api

I am developing a plugin for Outlook 2007/2010, and now I need to add a functionality to upload an email attachment directly to Dropbox folder. From there I need to share a link of that documents to my email recipients using dropbox API.

As I seen that same functionality is provided by DropBox website to share a link to list of names or email ids.
I need to do it by programmatically using C# 3.5 as my current working project is in C# 3.5 but if I need to move forward for C# 4.0 then no problem.

I have seen answer in one of the question [share folder via Dropbox Ruby API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126401/share-folder-via-dropbox-ruby-api) it will shown what i need to do, it will pass email ids to share a link, i need to do it with c# .net if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API doesn't currently supporting sharing folders. (That said, there's a shared folder beta going on right now you could join: https://dropboxapi.wufoo.com/forms/dropbox-shared-folder-api-beta-contact-info/.)

But you can create a share *link* to any file or folder via the [`/shares`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares) API call. (This is the equivalent of right-clicking on a file in Dropbox and choosing "Share Dropbox link.") So if you just need to send a link to people, that will work. If you need to invite people to join a shared folder, you'll need to wait for a shared folder API.

Comment: No, I don't want to support for sharing folders. i just need to upload file(s) to folder and send its shared link to list of email id's. As you said that using /Shares API i can achieve this, so can you have any working example or link which will do that type of task. Also can i pass list of email id's to share that link directly from dropbox.?

Comment: I already linked to the documentation for `/shares`. No, Dropbox won't send email for you with the share link. You would have to get the link and then send it out yourself.

Comment: S0, that's mean, I am not able to use functionality which dropbox site does, like when we right click on any file and select share link, it will come up with popup to enter list of email id(s) or name to share that link with them.. So we are not able to use that functionality with the use of any Dropbox API?

Comment: Correct. The API doesn't have any email-sending capability.

Answer (score 0):

1. get the sharelink using spring.social.dropbox
   ex: DropboxLink shareableLink = dropbox.GetShareableLinkAsync("/DROPBOX_FOLDER_NAME").Result;
2. send that link to the mail by creating System.Net.Mail.MailMessage and SmtpClient client objects.